# precise js daily repeat countdown timer

Tags: javascript, countdown

I've got this timer, which works just fine if I want it to count down to a straight hour, like 09:00. But it has to count down to 9:15 every day, and then reset.
Now this is what my code currently looks like:

```
<script>
var date;
var display = document.getElementById('time'); 
setInterval(function()
{ 
    date = new Date();

    var currentHours = date.getHours();
            var currentMinutes = date.getMinutes();

    var hours;
            var minutes;
            var seconds;

    if(currentHours == 09 && currentMinutes < 15)
    {
                minutes = 14 - date.getMinutes();
                seconds = 60 - date.getSeconds();
                display.innerHTML = 'Tid til næste bestilling: ' + minutes + ' minutter, ' + seconds + ' sekunder.';
    }
    else if(currentHours == 09 && currentMinutes > 15)
    {
                hours = 08 + (24 - currentHours);
                minutes = 74 - date.getMinutes();
                seconds = 60 - date.getSeconds();
                display.innerHTML = 'Tid til næste bestilling: ' + hours + ' timer, ' + minutes + ' minutter, ' + seconds + ' sekunder.';
    }
    else if(currentHours < 09)
    {
                hours = 08 - currentHours;
                minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
                seconds = 60 - date.getSeconds();
                display.innerHTML = 'Tid til næste bestilling: ' + hours + ' timer, ' + minutes + ' minutter, ' + seconds + ' sekunder.';
    }
    else if(currentHours > 09)
    {
                hours = 08 + (24 - currentHours);
                minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
                seconds = 60 - date.getSeconds();
                display.innerHTML = 'Tid til næste bestilling: ' + hours + ' timer, ' + minutes + ' minutter, ' + seconds + ' sekunder.';
    }
            else if(currentHours == 09 && currentMinutes == 15)
            {
                display.innerHTML = 'Bestillinger afsendt. Timeren starter om lidt igen.';
            }
}
,1000);
</script>
```

Now I know there is a more effecient way of doing this, I just cant seem to figure it out.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a much easy to implement hope this help. You can set what ever time you want. Just a notice this works only for a day and is in 24 hours system. This works even if the month changes.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
<script>
var date;
var display = document.getElementById('time'); 
setInterval(function()
{ 
    date = new Date();
    date1 = new Date(); 
    // you can set the hours, minutes, seconds here this is the date co compare
    date1.setHours(9);
    date1.setMinutes(15);
    date1.setSeconds(0);

    // here you make a date diff
    var diff =0;
    if(date1 < date){
        console.log('true');
        date1.setDate(date1.getDate()+1);
        diff = date1-date;
    }else{
    console.log('false');
        diff = date1-date;
    }

    // to avoid divided by 0
    if(diff ==0){       
        display.innerHTML = date+ ''+ date1 + ''+ date2+ ' Tid til næste bestilling: 24 timer, 0 minutter, 0 sekunder.';
        return;
    }
    // calculate hours, minutes, seconds
    hours = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60));
    diff -= hours *1000*60*60
    minutes = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60));
    diff -= minutes *1000*60;
    seconds = Math.floor(diff/(1000));  

    //finaly display
    display.innerHTML = d' Tid til næste bestilling: ' + hours + ' timer, ' + minutes + ' minutter, ' + seconds + ' sekunder.';

}
,1000);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much :)